# Calling a python function over the web using AJAX?

Tags: python, ajax, wsgi

I want to send a string to a python function I have written and want to display the return value of that function on a web page. After some initial research, WSGI sounds like the way to go. Preferably, I don't want to use any fancy frameworks. I'm pretty sure some one has done this before. Need some reassurance. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), it's a framework, but tiny and 100% WSGI 1.0 compliant.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Note: Flask sits on top of [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) and may need other libraries like sqlalchemy for DB work or jinja2 for templating.

Comment: It's worth noting that Flask is actually a layer over Werkzeug, which is not quite as tiny, though still small enough to be manageable.  It does mean you have about 3-4 implicit dependencies though, not merely Flask.  (As someone with similar goals to the OP, I don't consider this to be remotely a problem, compared to things like Turbogears2.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use cgi...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi

def myMethod(some_parameter):
    // do stuff
    return something

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

my_passed_in_param = form.getvalue("var_passed_in")
my_output = myMethod(my_passed_in_param)
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print my_output
```

This is just a very simple example.  Also, your content-type may be json or plain text... just wanted to show an example.

Comment: `cgi` is in the standard library.  This is as standalone as you can get.

Comment: does it require a web server like apache2 on the machine?

Comment: Presumably you have a web server installed? How else are you displaying your webpage?

Comment: You don't need a full blown web server to display "Hello World!" in HTML. You could write a quick script in python and import the base http server and execute it on some port.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Flask, [bottle](http://wiki.github.com/defnull/bottle/) is also simple and WSGI compliant:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello/:name')
def hello(name):
    return 'Hello, %s' % name

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
# --> http://localhost:8080/hello/world
```